Faster preprocessing for Arabic texts
Background
I'm analyzing a relatively large text-based Arabic dataset using Python (50,000 - 70,000 text files; total size ~5GB).
I want to segment, stem, and POS tag the dataset. I am aware of two Python libraries that can do these 3 tasks: farasapy and camel parser.
The problem
However, both of these Arabic-compatible Python libraries are rather slow for my purposes.
Based on a preliminary analysis of a subset of the data (n = 1000 text files), it is estimated that the camel parser library would take around 29 days to process the full dataset.
Question
Is there a more efficient method or library to do the 3 target tasks for Arabic texts?
I would appreciate your suggestions.

I will summarize what I did to enhance the performance of Camel Parser 2.0 and what worked:

used a virtual machine with a 64-core CPU: no significant increase in speed
used 64 cores while implementing several parallelization libraries (multiprocessing.Pool, multiprocess.Pool, concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor, mpire.WorkerPool): no significant increase in speed
used a powerful GPU: significant increase in speed (2x)
used a powerful GPU + parallelization: no significant increase in speed

Increasing GPU is key for the camel parser library.
